# How to partition a Flash Drive?

Tags: usb, software-rec, partitioning, usb-flash-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you partition a USB Thumb / Flash Drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/145710/how-do-you-partition-a-usb-thumb-flash-drive)

Do you know of any way on how to partition  a flash drive. Specifically an 8gb toshiba flash drive. I have tried using [lexar usb format](http://www.skidzopedia.com/2009/04/27/partition-usb-flash-drive-with-lexar-usb-format/).
But there was no luck, Do yo know of any application that could do flash drive partitioning.
I really wanted to have a bootable flash drive but can still store my files on a different partition.