# DiskPart Not Using Unallocated Space

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, diskpart

I'm trying to use `DiskPart` to create two partitions on my flash drive.  One for storage and one for a bootable OS.  I've used BootIt as suggested in this [question/answer,](https://superuser.com/questions/145710/how-do-you-partition-a-usb-thumb-flash-drive) however it doesn't seem to help one way or the other.  Perhaps it's out of date for Windows 7, the OS I'm working on, and yes I tried running BootIt in compatibility mode with admin privileges.

[image]

From `Disk Management` I wasn't able to do anything but format the current partition, change drive letter, and change drive label.

I then used `DiskPart`, which seems to be the best option, to create the first partition.  I can see the unallocated space available in `Disk Management` after doing this, but when I try to create another partition I get an error.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Tried using `extended` and got the same error message as above.  Retried from scratch using `offset` and received a different error.

[image]

Comment: Yup, I was wrong in my answer, hence the deletion.  Looks like my knowledge is out of date (probably remembering too much from my DOS days).

Comment: @Tom thanks for the answer though!  This little issue is bugging me.  I'm going to try a different flash drive and see if make any difference.

Comment: Have you tried GParted? Might be worth booting into GParted Live (http://www.gparted.org/livecd.php) and seeing if it works there.

Answer (score 6):

Flash Drives are recognized as removable media. According to Microsoft's description of the Diskpart Utility [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415):

*You cannot use Diskpart to create a partition on removable media. Windows supports at most one MBR partition on removable media.*

I believe this limitation also applies to Disk Management. You'll have to use 3rd party software to create multiple partitions on your flash drive. I've done it before using GParted on Lubuntu.