# USB Drive: How to get TWO FAT32 volumes on a 128GB stick, using Windows utilities?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I am following [some steps](https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/v9-how-to-format-usb-into-2-partitions-for-dashcam-and-music-windows.132130/) to make a USB stick that a Tesla can access, and am a tad alarmed (and frustrated) that I need to use a third party utility (Fat32Formatter) to format the 2nd partition to FAT32.

To be clear, I am creating a 32GB partition that is FAT32 (for the tesla dashcam) and the rest of the space for a single partition for music files.

The Tesla OS cannot access NTFS volumes, from what I understand.

I deleted the volumes on the USB, and then using diskpart did these commands:

```
convert gpt
create partition primary size=31000 align=1024
create partition primary align=1024
```

Then in Windows Disk Management, I formatted the first partition to FAT32. It works great. I can also, in Windows tools, format the second partition as exFAT or NTFS (and have tried that, and it works great). THE QUESTION: How to format the 2nd partition to FAT32?

There must be a native Windows way to do this?

I am on Windows10

**UPDATE**: I did, in fact, get the 2nd volume formatted FAT32 using a third party partition management tool. **The question on this thread stands**: Windows happily lets you CREATE A SECOND PARTITION on the USB stick. Windows also happily formats very large volumes as FAT32 when they are the only volume on the disk. But Windows does NOT allow you to FORMAT the second partition FAT32. The QUESTION is: How to do all of this in Windows-native land.

Comment: make sure you aren't exceeding the default 32GB limit of FAT32 on Windows; if you're trying to cut that entire drive into two equal parts that might be the issue you're running into. You might be able to get sneaky and just cut it into two NTFS partitions and convert them to FAT32 afterward.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you partition a USB Thumb / Flash Drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/145710/how-do-you-partition-a-usb-thumb-flash-drive).  For v1703 or later of Win 10, see http://woshub.com/creating-multiple-partitions-on-a-usb-drive-in-windows-10/.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks! This thread is not a duplicate (see my update above). Note that in the link you share, one partition is FAT32 and the other is NTFS... this thread is specifically how to get BOTH volumes formatted FAT32  (http://woshub.com/creating-multiple-partitions-on-a-usb-drive-in-windows-10/)

Comment: OK, retracted my duplicate close vote.

Answer (score -2):

It appears you're running Windows. As such; Open **Run** from the Start menu, and type in the box: `Diskmgmt.msc`.

This will open the Disk Management application. The rest is fairly self explanatory. Right-click on your target disk. Choose the *current* partitions, and choose `delete`. When finished. You should be able to right-click the disk, and choose `initialize`. This last step will allow Windows to initialize the disk in a manner that Windows is comfortable with. Which will further allow you to slice it up in the fashion that you desire, *and* in a way that Windows understands. Which *finally* allows you to accomplish all this in Windows. That's what you were hoping to do. Right? :)

UPDATE: For *those* having trouble(s) with the solution above. You *may* be limited to the **size** of your *second* partition. Adjust (the size) as required (by your copy of Windows).

Lastly; I performed the above operation within my copy of Windows to a 128Gb USB stick without problem(s). But others have expressed problems (see UPDATE above for a possible solution).